# Axure: Bulk-editing States

Tags: axure

Is there a way to bulk-edit states?

I have a dynamic panel ("dynPanel1") that contains several states which themselves contain a dynamic panels ("dynPanel2") who have different states of their own. Now I wish to adjust a state of the latter one ("dynPanel2"), I would have to go through every state of the parent dynamic panel ("dynPanel1") where dynPanel2 is used and for each one of these instances edit the state I want to alter.

The amount of work increases exponentially. Is there a way of editing dynPanel2's state just once and have it applied to every instance of dynPanel2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this is to use Masters.

You can convert any component (including dynamic panels) into a master. Then you can drag a master onto your mock-up, just like you can drag a component from the library.

Once it is a master then you can edit it and all occurrences will change.

To convert, just right-mouse click and choose the *Convert to Master*. Note that there are three options when you convert:

1. Place Anywhere
2. Lock to Master Location
3. BreakAway

I tend to use 1 and 2, I rarely use 3. 3 creates a clone that is not dependent on the master, so if you change the master, copies of it will not change.

Unfortunately you will have to replace all other individual instances of your dynamic panel. But once done, then you can just change once.

More info available at https://www.axure.com/support/reference/masters